# jQuery function not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function which prevents user from writing characters if an option is selected which works fine but the problem is that when I select another option which should allow characters it prevents it, so I tried adding event.stopPropagation() at the end but it doesn't seem to work. I am new to javascript

```js
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var thisPrice = '';

    switch (this.value) {
        case '1':
            thisPrice = 2;
            break;

        case '2':
             $(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {    
           $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
            if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
                       
             });
            break;
            

        case '3':
            event.preventDefault();
            thisPrice = 5;
            break;

        case '4':
            thisPrice = 6;
            break;
    }

    $('#showPrice').val(thisPrice);
});
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Choose size</option>
    <option id="size1">1</option>
    <option id="size2">2</option>
    <option id="size3">3</option>
    <option id="size4">4</option>
</select>
<input class="allownumericwithoutdecimal" type="text" id="showPrice" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dGHak/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to insert the following line of code at beginning of the function:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var thisPrice = '';
    $(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").off("keypress keyup blur");
    //...
});
```

When you add an event handler like `.on(...)` the function is registered, if you want to remove it you have to use the `.off(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing listeners on the input, why not just set up one listener for the input that will read the select and then act upon it?

You are working like this:

```
//'input' and 'select'    
$('select').on('change', function(e){
   if($(this).val) == something){
       $('input').on('change', function(){
           //add new listener based on select option.
       });
   }
});
```

When you could work like this:

```
//Just one listener needs to be added.
$('input').on('change', function(){
    var selectVal = $('select').val();
    if(selectVal == 1){
         //do something based on select value.
         doSomething();
    } else {
         doSomethingElse();
    }
});
```

Using the first way you'll have to remove the attached listeners everytime they change the option, using the second way you only need one listener.